# Bi-Lipschitz mappings

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, quasiconformal

Assume that we have a bi-Lipschitz mapping $f:\bar{\mathbb{B}}^n(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}^n$. The mapping need not be smooth anywhere and it may happen that it cannot be extended to a homeomorphism of a neighborhood of the ball.

> **Question.** *Is it possible to find a bi-Lipschitz mapping $g:\bar{\mathbb{B}}^n(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ that agrees with $f$ on the boundary, $f|_{\partial \mathbb{B}^n(0,1)}=g|_{\partial \mathbb{B}^n(0,1)}$ and such that $g$ is a diffeomorphism in an open subset or the ball?*

Intuitively it seems that such a mapping $g$ should exist. I am asking about being a diffeomorphism in *any* open subset of a ball, just a small neighborhood of a point.
However, I do not see how to prove it. Any smoothing arguments may destroy one-to-one property of the mapping.

**Edit.** Thank you for all of your comments. I found a proof in the literature and I will write it as an answer when I will have time. I believe that is an extremely difficult result and nobody understands its proof, including the authors. They say it explicitly and the story is quite twisted.

Comment: The situation is similar to CW-complex approximations.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f:\bar{\mathbb{B}}^n(0,1)\twoheadrightarrow D\ $ where $\ D\subseteq\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @WlodAA Yes. It is implied that the mapping is bi-Lipschitz onto the image and not onto the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$. What do you mean by CW-complex approximations? Is there a similar problem? Can you be more specific?

Comment: In the case of CW complexes, we have a theorem (not a "problem"): every cell map of CW-complexes is homotopic via cell maps to a regular cell map, i.e. every input cell has a regular point w.r. to the end-map, meaning that there is a non-zero Jacobian at such a point.

Comment: Have you thought about quasiconformal extension? If $n=2$, then the Ahlfors-Beurling extension should give you what you want. I believe there are generalizations of the Ahlfors-Beurling extension to higher dimension, see e.g. the paper "An N-dimensional version of the Ahlfors-Beurling extension" by Kovalev and Onninen.

Comment: I think the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0899v1 and references therein can give some indications about an answer to your problem.

Comment: The paper Connell, E. H. Approximating stable homeomorphisms by piecewise linear ones.Ann. of Math. (2)78(1963), 326–338. might be a good place to start. It will not answer your question, but the methods used there might be useful. However, Campbell, Daniel; Hencl, Stanislav; Tengvall, Ville, 
Approximation of $W^{1,p}$ Sobolev homeomorphism by diffeomorphisms and the signs of the Jacobian. Adv. Math. 331(2018), 748–829 suggests a negative answer.